# Saving entities with multi level back references

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a chain of entities defined in this way:

```
@Entity @Table("A")
class A {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Integer id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
  B b;
}

@Repository
interface RepositoryOfA implements JpaRepository<A, Integer> {}

@Entity @Table("B")
class B {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Integer id;

  @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
  A a;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
  C c;
}

@Embeddable
class CPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "b_id")
    val bId: Long
}

@Entity @Table("C")
class C implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    CPK id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    String data;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("b_id")
    B b;

}
```

I then try to add an entity of type B to existing entity of type B with children defined:

```
A a = repositoryOfA.findById(some_id).orElseThrow(...);
a.b = new B();
b.id = 0;
b.a = a;
b.c = new C();
c.id = new CPK();
c.id.b_id = 0; // ?????
c.b = b;
c.data = "hello";

repositoryOfA.save(a);
```

Then I get `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('C', CONSTRAINT 'c_id_fk' FOREIGN KEY ('b_id') REFERENCES 'B' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

I understand why that happens, I try to persist an entity with invalid `b_id`, which equals to zero. But the intuition tells me that Hibernate should have some annotation or so to bypass this because I do not want to do a manual 2-step save:
1) save an A with B where B.c = null
2) save an A with B with C

Is there a way to perform this operation in 1 call?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `@MapsId` was used incorrectly. According to the documentation `value` parameter of `@MapsId` should correspond to en existing entity property, not the column.

Strange thing that Hibernate does not complain on `@MapsId` referencing to en inexistent entity unlike it does in case of `@OneToOne(mappedBy='...')`